# Adding icon (.ico) images to files in Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, icons

I have a load of .bat files that I want to give custom .ico images (could be any other format, but I expect Windows Vista wants .ICOs). How do I add specific .ico images to files in Windows Vista?

I can't find a 'change icon' button or anything under the properties for the file. I know you can do this for folders, but is it possible for files?

I do not wish to change the icon for all batch files, but change the icon for each one individually. Thus file1.bat would have icon1.ico and file2.bat would have anotherIcon.ico

I'm using Windows Vista Ultimate (but I expect that this should be possible in each version?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put all your bat and ico files in a production folder then create shortcuts to the individual bat files in your launch folder (i.e. desktop, startmenu).

Then right click each shortcut and select properties to set icons.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great idea. However not perfect :( hope there is another way (as this is not really portable))

Comment: +1 I don't thing there are other options

Comment: If you have the skills or are feeling brave to learn, you could recode your scripts in Python and then use the py2exe utility to attach an icon to your new exe file check out http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/CustomIcons for a tut.

Comment: Okay, thanks. To bad there is no other way, but this will do for now.

Comment: No, there is no way to add an icon to a batch file because it is really nothing more than a plain-text file.